# Python Tkinter; .place() not working but .grid() and .pack() do

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to insert a Label with text on a frame. However, it does not appear with .place, even though it works fine with .grid and .pack.

```
label = tk.Label(master, text="test")
label.pack() # works
```

```
label = tk.Label(master, text="test")
label.grid() # works
```

```
label = tk.Label(master, text="test")
label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5) # doesn't work
```

```
label = tk.Label(master, text="test")
label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, width=500, height=500) # doesn't work
```

To be clear, I am not mixing the 3 methods. I'm running each attempt by separately.

My code structure is as follows:

```
class Window(tk.Tk)
   def __init__(self):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self)
      frame_init = Frame_0(self, 0)
      frame_init.pack()

class Frame(tk.Frame)
   def __init__(self, Window)
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, Window)

class Frame_0(Frame):
   def __init__(self, Window)
      super().__init__(Window)
      label = tk.Label(self, text="test")
      label.METHOD()   # METHOD is pack, grid, or place ()

... somewhere else

Window = Window()
Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Place needs arguments of x and y for the position, it don't have automatic placement like grid and pack. Add your error in the question

Comment: What error you are getiing?

Comment: No error. There is just nothing on the frame.

Comment: Check the below answer

Comment: Did you specify the size of the frame? If not, it may be zero if the widgets are using `place()`.  That's why you can't see the label.

Comment: Ah that was it. Answer it below if you want the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `place`, the size of the child won't affect the size of the master. Since you didn't specify a size for your frame its size will be 1x1. Your label *is* in the frame, but the frame is virtually invisible.

If you're going to use `place`, it's up to you to make sure that you are placing the widget inside a visible widget.

Answer (score -1):

Try anchoring method, it may be hiding inside

```
label.place(anchor = CENTER)
```

Maximize you window and check whether it's hiding somewhere too

Comment: Still nothing. Also, my window is setup as Window = tk.Tk(...) / Window.state("zoomed"), so it is maximized

Comment: Instead of relx and rely try x and y =10

Comment: I will get back to my pc and find you answers give me some time

Comment: Appreciate it. I'm stumped